# Could not find Constraint Layout inside Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-constraintlayout

Everything was working fine inside studio, but then I get error:

```
Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4.
```

Problem is that I can not install Constraint layout in Android Studio because I am using Ubuntu.I can not find SDK Tools(System Settings) to install manually like usually on MAC.

None of solutions here worked for me because they are mostly for MAC OS.

I am using Android 2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04, and Gradle 2.2.2.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Android 2.2

if you use **preview 1** than try with

**compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'**

Gradle

**classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'**

inside gradle wrapper

**distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip**

make sure you un-check from offline if you have not **gradle 2.14.1**

build Tools Version

**buildToolsVersion '
25
'**

Best way if you have installed gradle 2.14.1-all
then just go to your layout and then design tab, rignt click on your layout, click to convert,if you haven't installed Constraint lib you see a popup that says install lib, and click on ok. and then you can see in app level gradle file Constraint layout dependency added.

[image]